# Can't login to Juniper SRX from web gui

Tags: cisco, juniper

I have a Cisco 2911 router and a Juniper SRX550.  The Cisco 2911 is directly connected to the Juniper SRX550. I can ping both networks from either routers.

When I connect to https://172.16.128.1 from the Juniper SRX550, I'm able to login from the web gui.

[image]

[image]

But, when I go to https://172.16.128.1 from the Cisco router, get the "Your connection is not private page" just like on the SRX550, but then I get this.

[image]

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the (sanitized) configuration.

Comment: I would recommend you look at your juniper configuration, in particular I see this problem often under `system > services > web-management` take a look to make sure that the interface you are using is listed for `https`. For the sake of a basic setup / lab / debugging... try `interface all`.